# How do I write the text of the span under the input, and delete from the top?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a timeline. The name written on each input should be deleted from the top and written flat below when the input becomes active. It is not in the correct position at the moment. I need to fix this location. I also tried to do this by adding data-info but I guess this is not the right approach. Is it possible to provide this operation from the text written in span ?
I have added the codes and photos. I will be glad if you help.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}

.timetable-container {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 56.25vh;
  font-size: 0.5208vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-parent {
  margin-top: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.input-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.input-line {
  width: 3.5em;
  height: 3.5em;
  background-color: #7dad4c;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.input-line h2 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input {
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2.5px solid #7dad4c; 
  background-color: white;
}

.input::before,
.input::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #7dad4c;
  width: 10em;
  height: 0.7em; 
  max-width: 50px;
}

.input-line::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #7dad4c;
  width: 2em;
  height: 0.2em;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.input::before {
  left: calc(-4vw + 12.5px);
}

.input::after {
  right: calc(-4vw + 12.5px);
}

.input-line::after {
  right: calc(-4vw + 12.5px);
}

.input.active {
  background-color: #7dad4c;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.input span {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -300%;
  left: 30%;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.input span::after,
.input span::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.input span::after {
  content: attr(data-info); 
  color: #7dad4c;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 1.8em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.input span::before {
  top: -65px;
  width: 70px;
  transform: translateX(-5px) rotateZ(-45deg);
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-indent: -10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="timetable-container">
    <div class="section-timeline" style="height: 15%">
      <div class="flex-parent">
        <div class="input-flex-container">
          <div class="input-line">
            <h2>U1</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <span>Uhlandstr.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <span>Kurfurstendamm</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input active">
            <span data-info="Wittenbergplatz">Wittenbergplatz</span>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <span >Nollendorfplatz</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Current:
[image]

must be:
[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't produce your "current" result for me, probably due to how you use viewport-relative units. I have a 1920x1080 24" monitor, and your result looks tiny and has gaps.

Comment: Your `.input span::after {..}` tranforms need to be combined, otherwise *only* the last one will be executed. Also, assign a value to `bottom` in this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "must be" image shows that a marker only ever has *one* label:

We can **apply different styles** to `<span>` depending on whether its "input" has the `active` class, to change its position and its text's style. Example:

```js
/*Ignore; for toggling behaviour*/
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", evt => {
  document.querySelector(".input").classList.toggle("active", evt.target.checked);
});
```

```css
.input span {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input:not(.active) span {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 30%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.input.active span {
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #7dad4c;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*Ignore; representing your code*/
body {font-family:sans-serif}

.input {
  position: relative;
  border: .2rem solid #7dad4c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
}

.input::before, .input::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  width: 2rem;
  height: .2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #7dad4c;
}
.input::after {left:100%}

.input.active {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #7dad4c;
}

/*Ignore; presentational*/
#wrapper {
  height: 10rem;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<label><input type=checkbox> Has class <code>active</code>?</label>
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="input">
    <span>Wittenbergplatz</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

The lower label is actual content on the timeline; it should be in your HTML (or rather: in the DOM), and not be made with some CSS tricks.

So, **if you want both labels** on top and below, you should **use distinct elements**. You could position the extra element below the current marker with [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Example:

```css
.input-wrapper {
  margin-top: 6rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  width: fit-content;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 0 4rem;
}

.input {grid-row:1}

.highlight {
  grid-row: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.highlight span {
  position: absolute;
  top: .6rem;
  left: 50%;
  color: #7dad4c;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

/*Ignore; representing your code*/
body {font-family:sans-serif}

.input {
  position: relative;
  margin: -.2rem;
  border: .2rem solid #7dad4c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: .8rem;
  height: .8rem;
}
.input.active {
  width: 1.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #7dad4c;
}

.input::before, .input::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  width: 2rem;
  height: .2rem;
  background-color: #7dad4c;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.input::before {left:100%}

.input span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="input">
    <span>Some station</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input active">
    <span aria-current=location>Another station</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <span>A third station</span>
  </div>
  
  <!--
    The active input's index (for grid-column)
    and content can be found via JS.
  -->
  <div class="highlight" style="grid-column:2">
    <span aria-hidden=true>Another station</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The [`attr()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) only works on attributes; **you cannot "copy" an element's *content*** with it (or any other function) in CSS.